# How to add sprite as child sprite to another sprite in andengine?

Tags: android, andengine

I am developing game using andengine. I want to add a sprite as a child to another sprite so that sprite will rotate along with another sprite. Since I am new to andengine I didn't know how to add sprite as a child. By rotating main sprite the child has to rotate with it.

Some of them suggest to call sprite.attachChild() method to add as child but I can't get this method. I am extending BaseGameActivity.

Edited: Some of them says it's due to old version of andengine. Would anyone give me link for download new version of andengine?

Answer (score 1):

```
AnimatedSpriteHelicopter mSpriteHelicopter = new AnimatedSpriteHelicopter(0, 0, this.mTRHelicopter);

        mSpriteHelicopter.animate(50);
        this.mScene.getChild(GameLayers.HELICPTER_LAYER).attachChild(mSpriteHelicopter);
        this.mScene.registerTouchArea(mSpriteHelicopter);
        this.mScene.setTouchAreaBindingEnabled(true);

        // ==========================
        // Missile
        // ===========================
        AnimatedSpriteMissile mMissile = new AnimatedSpriteMissile(0, 0, this.mTRMissile);
        mMissile.animate(100);
        mSpriteHelicopter.attachChild(mMissile);
        return this.mScene;
```

Just a sample code. now missile will move with helicopter sprite :) very simple.
I have my own classes extended with AnimatedSprite.

Answer (score 0):

The source code is located at http://code.google.com/p/andengine/ and indeed sprite composition is a feature in the most recent version of AndEngine as verified in this [forum thread](http://www.andengine.org/forums/post12334.html?hilit=entitycontrainer#p12334).

I'm using it and can personally verify that it's functional.